# SQLite Function that performs additional queries

Tags: sqlite

I have written a custom SQLite function that transforms a string as it is copied from one table to another. It's very basic and has does its job well for quite a while. The query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (field1) SELECT MYTRANSFORM(field2) FROM Table2;
```

Now I need to modify the behavior of that function so that it does a lookup on another table and factors the result into how it transforms the value. Is that possible? Has anyone done it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible; you can execute other SQL queries from within your function, as long as you do not call your function recursively.